# Cloudera Namervice proxy setup with existing nameservice with HA

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, namenode

Repurpose the existing nameservice for the NameNode Proxies, and create a new nameservice to represent the NameNodes of the previous nameservice.

Comment: Please show your config files and attempts you've made

Comment: Application is already using the nameservice configured for HA with two name nodes.

Comment: Okay, great, please show the configuration

Comment: Only Configuration I have in hdfs-site.xml is     <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
    <value>cdhm1ns</value>